# boost 1.69 visual studio 2017 64-bit

Tags: c++, boost

Are there any tricks to building boost 1.69 in 64-bit using Visual Studio 2017 Pro?

My attempt (output is captured from a batch file I wrote to perform the build):

```
C:\boost-build\1.69.0>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.9.6
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
Building Boost.Build engine

Bootstrapping is done. To build, run:

    .\b2

<snipforbrevity>

C:\boost-build\1.69.0\boost_1_69_0>b2 -j2 toolset=msvc-14.1 address-model=64 architecture=x86  cxxflags="-DSSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1 -DSSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2 " --layout=tagged --without-python --without-mpi stage --stagedir=stage/amd64
Performing configuration checks

    - default address-model    : 32-bit
    - default architecture     : x86
```

I think I have the incantation correct to tease out 64-bit, but the b2 line prints `default address-model : 32-bit`.  The bootstrap.log appears to indicate that BOOST_JAM_ARCH is being set to x86 (the default if not specified in config_toolset.bat) and the final COPY line indicates it's copying bin.ntx86_64\bjam.exe... so why the discrepancy in b2's output?

I do *not* wish to download pre-built binaries.  Not only are they only at 1.66, but we build these libs across many OS's and platforms, so we prefer to patch and build ourselves.

Comment: i don't have 2017 but normally when i build boost i open the appropriate command prompt. that ensures i have built it with the correct version.

Comment: Setting the proper command environment is the first thing done prior to calling bootstrap.bat.

Comment: *Not only are they only at 1.66* -- [Are you sure?](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well, I stand corrected... I looked at the green button and scanned no further. :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the comments you show it seems to work and build the correct libraries.
For example it generates
libboost_stacktrace_windbg_cached-vc141-mt-**x64**-1_69.lib

Comment: So, you were right, it is building the right libs.  Running `dumpbin /headers libboost_chrono.lib | c:\cygwin\bin\grep machine` shows either "x86" or "x64", so the process is correct, just the output of b2.exe when it prints "default address-model" is incorrect in the 64-bit case.